# Second Highest and first highest value

Tags: excel, vba

I have five players out of which I need to select two best players.

Sample Data.
Name    Batting Average
Sourav  40.73
Sachin  44.83
Anil    10.54
Zaheer  12
Rahul   39.17

I have tried for loops. However, I am not able to get the desired answer.

Below is a code.

enter code here`

```
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim highestValue As Double, secondHighestValue As Double

    Sub nss()


    Set rng = Selection
    highestValue = 0
    secondHighestValue = 0

    'Find Highest Value
    For Each cell In rng

    Next cell

    If cell.Value > highestValue Then highestValue = cell.Value

    'Find Second Highest Value
    For Each cell In rng

    Next cell

    If cell.Value > secondHighestValue And cell.Value < highestValue Then secondHighestValue = cell.Value

    MsgBox "Second Highest Value is " & secondHighestValue


    End Sub
```

I am getting an error "run time error 91","Object variable or with block not set"

Additionally, I am also looking for the first highest value to get printed after the second-highest value to get printed.

Hope for some good results.

Regards,
Aiyub

Comment: The `For Each cell in rng` begins the loop, and the `Next cell` ends it. You don't have any code *inside* the loop. Move the code inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following BigBen's tip, you need to move your `If` statements inside the existing `For Each` loops. You also need to end each `If` statement with an `End If`, otherwise your macro still won't work.

On top of that, do not declare variables (`Dim`) outside of your `Sub`, unless you want them to be re-used in the current module (i.e. "module-level variable").

I also expanded your MsgBox to print the first highest value (as per your request).

```
Sub nss()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim highestValue As Double, secondHighestValue As Double

    Set rng = Selection
    'highestValue = 0
    'secondHighestValue = 0

    'Find Highest Value
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value > highestValue Then
            highestValue = cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell

    'Find Second Highest Value
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value > secondHighestValue And cell.Value < highestValue Then
            secondHighestValue = cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell

    MsgBox "Second Highest Value is " & secondHighestValue & vbNewLine & "First Highest Value is " & highestValue
End Sub
```

P.S. Alternatively, you can use `Large` function...

```
Sub nss()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim highestValue As Double, secondHighestValue As Double

    Set rng = Selection

    'Find Highest Value
    highestValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(rng, 1)

    'Find Second Highest Value
    secondHighestValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(rng, 2)

    MsgBox "Second Highest Value is " & secondHighestValue & vbNewLine & "First Highest Value is " & highestValue
End Sub
```